# Troubles with array of objects inside my interface in TypeScript & Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, array.prototype.map

I started converting my code to TypeScript but for some reason i cannot get to work.

The code does not give an error but it does not show the list.

```
type song = {
    id: number,
    artist: string,
    titre: string;
    links: string[] | number,
    has_youtube_link: number,
    has_picture: number,
    hour: number,
    minutes: number,
    votes: number
}
interface Songs {
    listOfSongs: song[]
}
const LastPlayedSongs: React.FC = () => {
    const [songs, setSong] = useState<Songs | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("APILink")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                setSong(response);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [])
    return (
       <>
           <ul>
               {songs?.listOfSongs?.map((song) => (
                   <li key={song.id}>{song.titre}, {song.id}</li>
                ))}
           </ul>
       </>
    );
}
```

If i use the song type directly instead of the Songs interface it works.

```
type song = {
    id: number,
    artist: string,
    titre: string;
    links: string[] | number,
    has_youtube_link: number,
    has_picture: number,
    hour: number,
    minutes: number,
    votes: number
}

const LastPlayedSongs: React.FC = () => {
    const [songs, setSong] = useState<song[] | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("APILink")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                setSong(response);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {songs?.map((song) => (
                    <li key={song.id}>{song.titre}, {song.id}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```

Does anyone knows how to make the first one wor or give some informations on what I am doing wrong.

Kind regards

Comment: Can you add the console.log of the repsonse?

Comment: @Domino987 it is a simple array like this : `(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 21520, artist: "Blondie", titre: "Rapture", links: "<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/be/album/rap…:110px;height:40px;background-size:contain;"></a>", has_youtube_link: "0", …}`

Comment: You should use capital letters for both types and interfaces.  It makes it easier to distinguish between variables and types.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank you for the advice, will change it and avoid doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should eighther change your interface or set the state correctly to the object attribute.

1. `type Songs = song []` then `useState<Songs>([])` and then `setSong(response)`
2. what you currently have as interface then `setSong({listOfSongs:response})`

preferably don't make your state nullable, it is an array and initially can be an empty array

Comment: The two options do work, but which one would you recommend ? is one better than the other ?

Comment: Well if the state is supposed just to keep the response, we don't need to introduce a new attribute. So I will say the first approach is better.